# Encryption with customer provided key in a multi tenant Postgres JSONB DB

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant, postgresql-json

We use Postgres's JSONB structure for NoSQL usage.

We have a multi tenant application where for each tenant we create separate tables . So for e.g. if i have 100 tenants then i have 100 tables.

Now we want to have encryption for the data in the tables with the tenant provided key. Is it possible to encrypt tables in a same database with different keys. ?

Do i have to move towards schema separation or towards having separate databases per tenant to support customer provided key encryption ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Do you want to encrypt the tables or specific columns in tables?